# Where to ask where I can download certain files I need?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

For using [Jquery Combobox](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox) Plugin

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base
/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
```

Three of above files are easily available to download. But I am unable to find the last one anywhere. So I need some guidance about its download url, and where to download it.

I did not know where to ask this question, so I'm asking here with the site-rec tag. Please guide me where to ask such a question, because I have seen they are closed as not constructive on SO.

Comment: @jmort253: The latter.

Comment: @jmort253 [Jquery combox](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox) uses a file as `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />`. I had downloaded all bundle from your told link already. But unable to find this file there. However You have given the answer according to SO policy whether it helps me in what i need or not, so you can post it as answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There really isn't an appropriate place on Stack Exchange for locating resource links, even though sometimes it is easy to get stuck looking for something. We all have days where, for whatever reason, our ability to type the right search terms just seems to evade us.

So instead, I'd suggest taking a coffee break to rest your brain, then come back and hit Google with some different search terms. Sometimes if I get stuck on a search I'll take a 5 minute break, and it helps. But on Stack Exchange, they would most likely be closed as too localized, not a real question, or not constructive. Good luck! :)

Oh, and as long as you don't do it too much, there's always chat, if you have at least 20 reputation. Again, just don't do it too often, lest ye be known as a [help vampire](http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/). :)