# Where do I ask about downloading an audio file from a website?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Long story short: I wanted to download the audio file from [here](http://www.srf.ch/sendungen/sounds/radiohead-live-am-openair-st-gallen). As there is no download link, and it's probably not even supposed to be downloaded at all, I was searching for some other way to get the audio file.

After some Chrome <kbd>F12</kbd> magic I actually found the file and could download it. But if I wouldn't have found out, where would I ask this question? My best guess was [superuser.com](https://superuser.com/), but it didn't seem to fit there either. Any better suggestion?

**Edit**: As a lot of discussion is about the fact whether it's illegal / morally questionable to achieve my goal: I explained my (moral) intentions in a comment below. When it comes to legality, living in [Switzerland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switzerland) gives you quite a lot of freedom in using [published content for personal use](https://www.admin.ch/opc/de/classified-compilation/19920251/index.html#a19). I want to stress that I don't mean to gain any other benefit in downloading the audio file than to listen to it by myself.

**Edit2**: For the sake of completeness: Either I'm completely blind or they really added it just today, but now there is a download button on the page :-)

Comment: So, you want a site where you can get advice on how to steal audio content from a website?

Comment: @Catija, how can we call it stealing? What if he owns the audio and want to do some penetration testing? There are a lot of commercial software available for this purpose. I think this question comes under software recommendations

Comment: @Anand so you're saying that the OP is a member of the band Radiohead?

Comment: @Catija, no, I don't mean like that. This is definitely not stealing (atleast 80%). If the audio is copyrighted, he will be allowed to hear only after paying. Chrome will not have the link if he is not allowed to hear the audio

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not. I know I'm legally speaking in a grey area, but: I bought every single record of them, and I know this recording is not gonna be available for sale. If it was I would gladly pay for it. I don't want to distribute it in any way, I just want to be able to listen it by myself even after the article is taken down.

Comment: @Anand Everything is copyrighted. A particular website may be given permission to present the audio for free but that doesn't make it OK for people to rip it from the site. If it was there for general consumption/reproduction, there would be a download link.

Comment: @Catija, the answer is in your comment "to present the audio for free". if the website doesn't want users to download it, then its their fault for providing the link in browser directly. The website should fix this vulnerability or mention that downloading is an offence.

Comment: @Anand People misusing the system does not make it legal.

Comment: @Catija, we cannot call this misusing. Normally, we will right click any link and choose "Save link as" option in the context menu. Instead OP tried a different approach. These options are commonly available in all browsers so we should not blame OP.

Comment: if websites want the audio to be secure, they should provide it like a live feed (web radio or something) instead of attaching the link in browser. If the OP uses a recording software and records this audio, then we can call it stealing

Comment: Can we keep this on-topic? OP didn't ask if this was legal or not and even that may vary from country to country. Discussing that will bring nothing I think.

Comment: there is a similar question like this http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158277

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where to ask where I can download certain files I need?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158277/where-to-ask-where-i-can-download-certain-files-i-need)

Comment: That is a *where* question, not a *how* question. Those are essentially different @anand

Comment: content of the question might be different but answer can be applied to this question

Comment: *"Switzerland gives you quite a lot of freedom in using published content for personal use."* Yes, and Nigeria gives its citizens a lot of freedom for using other people's money as well.  Doesn't mean its moral to do so. :|

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My bet would be on SuperUser since this is a general software usage question (the browser in this case).

I would prepare for downvotes if I were you, since some communities don't like people trying to do questionable things (in this case it *feels* like you want to 'steal' someone else's music).

Your question doesn't sound like it, but it could be a question for [Information Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/), if the question is about the security implications or how to prevent against such actions.